# How to reduce the insertion time of data with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, optimization

I'm inserting data into database in the following way:

Controller:

```
foreach($cData as $data){

    $ins['name'] = $data['name'];

    $bonus = $this->calBonus($data['bonus']); //calculates bonus.

    $ins['bonus'] = $bonus;

    //similarly there are few more data which are assigned to the $ins array;

    $res = $this->myModel->insertData($ins); // for inserting data;

}
```

Model:

```
function insertData($ins){
    $res = $this->db->insert('bonus',$ins);
    if($res){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I have `300000` data in `$cdata`. For one data insertion it is taking `100 milliseconds`. So for complete insertion it would take 8+ hours.

Now how to optimize this insertion? Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: are you parsing a csv file or what?

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in a transaction. It will execute faster. Using PHP's mysqli functions instead of CodeIgniter's DB library would possibly decrease the execution time as well.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo nope not CSV, $cData is gets data from database.

Comment: then you are doing it wrong brother, there is way to get that on the database layer. Use it like this

`insert into table(col1, col2, col3) select col1,col2, col3 from table_2`, this will be done on database and it extremely fast.

Comment: @BrianGottier 
I actually have a doubt If there is some logic to perform before insertion which is optimized one:

1) Inserting through CodeIgniter.
2) Inserting through PHP, MySQL.
3) Writing stored procedure in MySQL.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo  I am not just copying data from one table to other, I need to perform some operations on the data and even add additional data to it from other table and finally insert it.

Comment: that's fine then

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo do you know any better approach for this and
which is better stored procedures or PHP?

Comment: are you are doing some processing and getting things done in 3 seconds, it's good enough.

Comment: My bad 5000 data got inserted in 3 seconds. I thought 300000. Still batch insertion reduced the time. Initially my function took 10 mins for performing operations and insertion. Now it took 5 mins with the help of batch insertion. I'm still working on it to optimise it further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use batch insert function

```
$mainArray = array();
foreach($cData as $data){

    $ins['name'] = $data['name'];

    $bonus = $this->calBonus($data['bonus']); //calculates bonus.

    $ins['bonus'] = $bonus;
    // push array in main array
    array_push($mainArray,$ins);
}

if($mainArray != array()){

    $this->db->insert_batch('YOUR_TABLE_NAME', $mainArray)
}
```

Refrence : [Here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html)

Comment: It worked, compete array got inserted in 3 seconds. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: My bad, 5k records got inserted in 3 seconds which is far better than normal insertion.